# What is causing the error 'ORA-00904: "o0"."ObservationId1": invalid identifier' in my EF Core query?

Tags: entity-framework-core

I'm getting an **ORA-00904: invalid identifier** error when I include a foreign collection of data.

My simplified classes are

```
[Table("OBSERVATION", Schema = Constants.TABLE_SCHEMA_NAME)]
public class Observation : IEntity<int>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("OBSERVATIONID")]
    public override int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ObservationCba>? ObservationCbas { get; set; } = default;
}

[Table("OBSERVATIONCBA", Schema = Constants.TABLE_SCHEMA_NAME)]
public class ObservationCba : IEntity<long>
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Column("OBSERVATIONCBAID")]
    public override long Id { get; set; }

    [Column("OBSERVATIONID")]
    public long ObservationId { get; set; }
}
```

And the error occurs on this query

```
var observations = await _dbContext.Observations
    .Include(c => c.ObservationCbas)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Do I have my classes setup wrong, or do I need to `Include` differently? What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I spent 4 hours yesterday and 1 hour today searching for the problem. I figured it out 20 minutes after posting here.

The error is caused by inconsistent types. `Observation.Id` is defined and an `int`; `ObservationCba.ObservationId` is a `long`. Changing `Observation.Id` to a `long` fixed my problem.